.ply to .bin(velodyne) conversion
I am working on 3d object detection, I have point cloud data in form of .ply. I came across so many github repos where most of them are using KITTI dataset.
I tried to use PointPillars algorithm for 3d object detection but it was accepting point cloud data only in the form of .bin(velodyne). Is there any way to convert .ply to .bin(velodyne) or to give .ply files as input to PointPillars ?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

To convert your .ply point cloud files to .bin format (which is required for PointPillars), you can use the following Python code. It allows you to load .ply files, convert them to binary format, and save them with a .bin extension. This should make your point cloud data compatible with algorithms like PointPillars.
import os
from typing import Union
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
from glob import glob
from open3d.geometry import PointCloud

def make_directory(directory_path: str) -> None:
    """Creates a directory if it does not exist."""
    if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
        os.makedirs(directory_path)

def load_point_cloud(file_or_directory_path: str, file_extension: str = 'ply') -> Union[np.ndarray, PointCloud]:
    """
    Loads a point cloud file or all point cloud files in a directory.

    Args:
        file_or_directory_path (str): Path to a point cloud file or directory.
        file_extension (str): Extension of the point cloud files (default is 'ply').

    Returns:
        Union[np.ndarray, PointCloud]: The loaded point cloud(s).
    """
    if os.path.isdir(file_or_directory_path):
        point_clouds = []
        point_cloud_files = glob(f"{file_or_directory_path}/*.{file_extension}")
        for file_path in point_cloud_files:
            point_cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(file_path, format=file_extension)
            point_clouds.append(point_cloud)
        return np.array(point_clouds)
    
    elif os.path.isfile(file_or_directory_path):
        return o3d.io.read_point_cloud(file_or_directory_path, format=file_extension)

def convert_point_cloud_to_bin(point_cloud: PointCloud, output_file_path: str, file_extension: str = 'ply') -> None:
    """
    Converts a point cloud to binary format (.bin).

    Args:
        point_cloud (Union[str, PointCloud, np.ndarray]): The point cloud or its path.
        output_file_path (str): Path for the output .bin file.
    """
    if isinstance(point_cloud, str):
        point_cloud = load_point_cloud(file_or_directory_path=point_cloud, file_extension=file_extension)
    
    output_file_path += "" if output_file_path.endswith(".bin") else ".bin"
    np.asarray(point_cloud.points).astype('float32').tofile(output_file_path)

def batch_convert_point_clouds_to_bin(input_directory_path: str, output_directory_path: str, file_extension: str = 'ply') -> None:
    """
    Converts all point clouds in a directory from their current format to .bin format.

    Args:
        input_directory_path (str): Path to the directory containing point cloud files.
        output_directory_path (str): Path to the directory where .bin files will be saved.

    Raises:
        ValueError: If input_directory_path is neither a file nor a directory.
    """
    if not os.path.isdir(output_directory_path):
        make_directory(output_directory_path)

    if os.path.isfile(input_directory_path):
        file_name_without_extension = os.path.basename(input_directory_path).split('.')[0]
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory_path, file_name_without_extension)
        convert_point_cloud_to_bin(point_cloud=input_directory_path, output_file_path=output_file_path)
    
    elif os.path.isdir(input_directory_path):
        point_cloud_files = glob(f"{input_directory_path}/*.{file_extension}")
        for file_path in point_cloud_files:
            file_name_without_extension = os.path.basename(file_path).split('.')[0]
            output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory_path, file_name_without_extension)
            convert_point_cloud_to_bin(point_cloud=file_path, output_file_path=output_file_path)
    
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"'{input_directory_path}' is neither a file nor a directory.")

How to Use:

Single .ply File: Call convert_point_cloud_to_bin with the path to your .ply file and the desired output path.
Batch Conversion: Use batch_convert_point_clouds_to_bin to convert all .ply files in a directory.

This code should help you convert your .ply files to the .bin format used by the KITTI dataset, making them compatible with PointPillars.

I modified the code for here: https://gist.github.com/AlexPasqua/f34994a0b0f8ee33f8730d6e660d55b5#file-pointclouds_pcd_to_bin-py
